# tooltip under mouse cursor - flickering

Tags: vb.net

I have set tooltip under mouse cursor, but It's flashing all the time, even If cursor doesn't move. Any ideas on how to prevent tooltip flickering ?

Code:

```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseHover


        Dim cur = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

        If cur.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso cur.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then

            DataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Help

            ToolTip1.Active = True
            Dim cp = Cursor.Position
            cp.Y += CInt(Cursor.Size.Height * 0.2)
            cp.X += CInt(Cursor.Size.Width * 0.8)
            ToolTip1.Show("Details...", Me, PointToClient(cp))

        Else
            DataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            ToolTip1.Active = False
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: What flickers, the cursor or the tool tip? Also, where do you execute this code?

Comment: Sorry, I edited question, tooltip flickers, and I have this code in Datagrid_mouseMove event.

Comment: Now I haven't used a data grid very much so I don't know how that control behaves, but what happens if you try this in the `MouseHover` event instead?

Comment: Lol, It happens what I was looking for :)... It works now without flickering. I would eventually came to this point, but sooner is better..Thanks !!...Make a way to mark your comment as answer.

Comment: But now another problem comes up - I have code that uses x and y coordinates for mouse cursor, and "x,y" are not a member of Mouse_hover....Strangely, code works, but debugger marks It as error.

Comment: I'll write an answer about it, but I don't understand what you mean with your second comment? If you want the cursor's coordinates, `Cursor.Position` should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing it appears that once the ToolTip is shown, the `DataGridView` temporarily loses focus. When it regains the focus the `MouseMove` event gets called again which causes the ToolTip to close and reshow itself again, and so it continues infinitely, eating CPU and some RAM, until you move the mouse outside a cell.

The simplest way to fix this is to make it check wether the mouse has moved or not since the last time `MouseMove` was called, then only reshow the ToolTip ***if*** the mouse has moved.

I used the `CellMouseMove` and `CellMouseLeave` events instead to save you the additional checking if the mouse is over a cell:

```
Dim PreviousCursorPos As New Point(-1, -1)

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseMove
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso _
        PreviousCursorPos <> Cursor.Position Then 'If the mouse is not in the same position as before, then execute the code.

        DataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Help
        ToolTip1.Active = True

        Dim cp = Cursor.Position
        cp.Y += CInt(Cursor.Size.Height * 0.2)
        cp.X += CInt(Cursor.Size.Width * 0.8)

        ToolTip1.Show("Details...", Me, Me.PointToClient(cp))

        PreviousCursorPos = Cursor.Position
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseLeave
    DataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    ToolTip1.Active = False
End Sub
```

The ToolTip will flicker a bit when moving the mouse, but once it's still there won't be a problem.

Comment: Ok, see my edited question, you'll see full code now, in mouse_Hover event. I use x and y coordinates to show help cursor only on Datagrid cells, rather than whole datagrid control - and with it goes tooltip text. I dont know how Cursor.Position could work same way.

Comment: As pointed before, this code strangely works, but with errors, and only If OwnerDraw property is set to True. However If I try to change backcolor of tooltip, flickering appears again.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 : Updated answer. -- Seems strange that you'd need `OwnerDraw` to be True... By the way, can you even change the background of a ToolTip? Or aren't you using the standard one?

Comment: As I said, code works with OwnerDraw to true, but debugger underlines "x" and "y" as It's not a member of "e As EventArgs" in Mouse Hover, so It's not good. Yes you can draw backcolor of standard Tooltip - with OwnerDraw set to true and using Tooltip Draw event (e.DrawBackground(), e.DrawBorder(),e.DrawText()).

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 : But my edit should solve your `x` and `y` variable problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but It's not working, unfortunally. It shows tooltip only on 1st mouse hover, then It stucks, not following cursor. And cursor doesn't change until you leave datagrid, so another problem there.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 : That's because you handle the `Hover` event for the entire DGV. You'd have to subscribe to the `CellMouse****` events. `CellMouseHover` doesn't seem to exist, but the rest does. See a list here (you could use `CellMouseEnter`): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 : I might actually have a solution for you. See my update.

Comment: I'm afraid not, again. It works fine with datagrid cells, even tooltip background colour changes without flickering. But then It stucks with cursor - It's showing help cursor all over datagrid, except first row /column. And tooltip follows cell position, not cursor. My best option so far is to use Mouse_Move event with OwnerDraw set to True, but this flickers Tooltip If I change background colour.

Comment: I'll test whatever events I could use. maybe some will work will all things together :)

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 : Mouse fixed (update). But the position doesn't stick with the cell, it's your position calculation that is not correct. I tried to fix it but ToolTips seems to handle it differently, which makes it hard to put it properly where the cursor's at. -- Also, it does work over the entire grid for me (make sure you remove your old `Mouse****` events).

Comment: let us continue in chat...YOur code doesn't fix the cursor problem - once I move to datagrid cells on 1st attempt, everything is o.k. Then cursor wont go away If I hover over datagrid & tooltip on cells appears in different locations when hovering the cells.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120246/discussion-between-visual-vincent-and-luckyluke82).